# Decimal to HH:MM Conversion

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and I want to update the `Duration` column which of datatype `Decimal` to `HH:MM` format.

```
ECode        Duration
101           101.75
101           69.56
102           54.60
103           54.97
```

The output should be like this:

```
ECode        Duration
101           102.15
101           69.56
102           55
103           55.37
```

We are calculating the time after the decimal and if after decimal 60 or more then 60 will be there we are adding 1 before decimal and remaining after subtraction from 60 we are showing as it is.

Example 101.75, here after decimal 75 is there so firstly we check it is greater than or equal to 60. If yes then subtract 60 and add 1 before decimal and put the remaining 15 after decimal. So the result should be 102.15.

Please share query if possible to solve this issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Also: which **version** of SQL Server?? 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would do something like ("pseudo" code of some sort):

```
String reorder(String x) {
  String parts[] = x.split(.);
  if(parts.length < 2) x;
  // eval as integers:
  if(parts[1] < 60) return x;
  if(parts[1] > 60) return (parts[0]+(parts[1]/60))+"."+(parts[1]%60);
  return parts[0]+1;
}
```

But exactly how you do it depends whether you're doing in a script, some application and the language you're using...

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
update thistable 
set    duration = duration + 0.4 
where  duration - floor(duration) >= 0.6
```

Comment: +1 I almost downvoted for thinking you completely missed the point.

Answer (score 2):

```
update YourTable set
  Duration =  floor(Duration) + 
              cast(((Duration - floor(Duration))*100) as int) / 60 +
              cast((cast((Duration - floor(Duration)) * 100 as int) % 60) as float) / 100
```

Comment: This Solve my issue but not giving accurate result in decimal format as the result is Coming as Round Off.Thanks a lot for the logic and it helps me...