# Minutes Conversion to HH:MM Format through Update Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which have Duration as a column which contains Sum of Minutes and i want to convert all the Duration it in to HH:MM Format.

```
ECode        Duration
101           186
102           1446
103           1116
```

The output should be like this:

```
ECode        Duration
101           3.06
102           24.06
103           18.36
```

I want to do it with an Update statement and want to update all the rows like this .
Looking for the Query which may slve my problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal to HH:MM Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513851/decimal-to-hhmm-conversion)

Comment: You should be able to work it out with the examples given in your other question. If not, post what you have tried and where you got stuck. This is starting to look very much like *give me the codez*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ECode,
        CAST(Duration AS INT) AS Duration
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    SELECT CAST(Duration/ 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(Duration % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS Duration
FROM
    CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is as follows:

```
SELECT ECode
    CAST(Duration/ 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(Duration % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS Duration
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: i mGetting error in sql server 2008 when trying this query and the error message is  "The data types float and int are incompatible in the modulo operator."

Comment: @Dharmendra - sounds like your Duration column is a FLOAT then? You can try applying a CAST around Duration to an INT - e.g. "CAST(Duration AS INT)" in place of each reference to "Duration" in my example